# Headless chrome is taking too long to open any url as compared to full chrome

Tags: google-chrome, headless-browser, puppeteer, google-chrome-headless

When I am trying to open pages in Headless chrome through Puppeteer it is taking much time as compared to the Full Chrome.
I am trying to open normal websites in **1366*768** viewport to take their screenshots , But it takes a lot of time to open normal pages in Headless Chrome.
Below are results of my test which I performed by opening 10 urls using both **headless:true** and **headless:false** flags

### Headless:False (Full Chrome)

- google.com: 14279.508ms
- hacks.mozilla.org: 16213.428ms
- apple.com: 17465.563ms
- gmail.com: 18820.810ms
- dell.com: 19853.047ms
- snapdeal.com: 20722.319ms
- flipkart.com: 22994.769ms
- microsoft.com: 23404.095ms
- hp.com: 23963.416ms
- amazon.com: 27175.416ms

### Headless:true (Headless Chrome)

- google.com: 157191.829ms
- gmail.com: 159343.018ms
- snapdeal.com: 309226.297ms
- hacks.mozilla.org: 337393.393ms
- microsoft.com: 369301.073ms
- dell.com: 397798.479ms
- apple.com: 398685.341ms
- flipkart.com: 576905.928ms
- hp.com: 1118683.968ms
- amazon.com: 2372061.166ms

### **Steps to reproduce:**

1. Execute below script in both Headless Chrome and Full Chrome by setting headless:true and headless:false flag.
2. Time difference between two methods is huge, In Headless Chrome it looks like it get stuck for some time .

### **OS Config**

Windows 7
Puppeteer version 0.13.0
I7 16GB Ram

### **Code :**

```
var puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

async function capture(url) {
//console.log(url +': Started');
console.time(url);
const browser = await puppeteer.launch({headless:true});
const page = await browser.newPage();
page.setViewport({ width: 1366, height: 768 });
await page.goto('http://'+url, { waitUntil: 'networkidle2', timeout: 3000000 
});
await page.screenshot({path: url+'.jpg',fullPage: true});
browser.close();
console.timeEnd(url);

}

capture('hacks.mozilla.org');
capture('google.com');
capture('amazon.com');
capture('flipkart.com');
capture('snapdeal.com');
capture('dell.com');
capture('gmail.com');
capture('apple.com');
capture('microsoft.com');
capture('hp.com');
```

Please let me know if I am missing something or how we can resolve this issue.

Answer (score 2):

You forgot `await` before `browser.close()`. Additionally, I don't think that this code test sites like you wish to - you open at once all tests! I suppose this version is what you are looking for:

```js
var puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

async function capture(url) {
    console.time(url);
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless: true });
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    page.setViewport({ width: 1366, height: 768 });
    await page.goto('http://' + url, { waitUntil: 'networkidle2', timeout: 3000000 });
    await page.screenshot({ path: url + '.jpg', fullPage: true });
    await browser.close();
    console.timeEnd(url);
}

(async () => {
    await capture('hacks.mozilla.org');
    await capture('google.com');
    await capture('amazon.com');
    await capture('flipkart.com');
    await capture('snapdeal.com');
    await capture('dell.com');
    await capture('gmail.com');
    await capture('apple.com');
    await capture('microsoft.com');
    await capture('hp.com');
})();
```

My times for MacBook pro 2015:

`headless: false`

```js
hacks.mozilla.org: 4621.447ms
google.com: 2834.090ms
amazon.com: 9421.097ms
flipkart.com: 16224.524ms
snapdeal.com: 9883.090ms
dell.com: 4675.504ms
gmail.com: 5387.398ms
apple.com: 4229.881ms
microsoft.com: 4017.234ms
hp.com: 6187.240ms
```

---

`headless: true`

```js
hacks.mozilla.org: 3888.767ms
google.com: 2220.519ms
amazon.com: 5703.504ms
flipkart.com: 17623.040ms
snapdeal.com: 7237.338ms
dell.com: 4267.592ms
gmail.com: 3167.475ms
apple.com: 3636.282ms
microsoft.com: 4190.694ms
hp.com: 5579.363ms
```